# meaning of phrase "Get all huffy and weird"?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

I am watching Friends series (season 9 episode 13). In the beginning, I faced a dialog which I cannot get the meaning of this phrase:

> "Just give me a second to get all huffy and weird like you".

huffy means touchy and easily irritated or offended. I ask about this phrase from other and they said, if you are familiar with this series and Ross Character you would understand this better. Because the other side of this dialog is Chanlder who is a character that make fun of every things and also, this dialog is for him. so he mocked on Ross.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the context, but "huffy" means "easily annoyed".  It comes from the "huff" sound that people make by breathing out loudly when they are annoyed.

Weird means "strange". Everything else is literal. She asks for a little time to allow her to become huffy and weird. She says that the other person is already huffy and weird, which is an insult.

The idea of someone asking for a little time to become "huffy and weird" is very odd, and is part of the joke.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,

Comment: yes you are right, huffy means touchy and easily irritated or offended. I ask about this phrase from other and they said, if you are familiar with this series and Ross Character you would understand this better. Because the other side of this dialog is Chanlder who is a character that make fun of every things, and also, this dialog is for him. so he mocked on Ross.